# How to change value if variable is nested array of objects? (example 2)

Tags: javascript

I have a script for tests in which I pass values from the input to the result.

```
1."result": {
                    "id": "#id#",
                    "number": "#number#",
                        }


"methods": [
                {
                    "id": "001",
                    "input": {
                              "id": "2",
                              "number": "2585112"}
]
```

If the result variable is an object, then values I replace the values with the as follows (it works):

```
if (result){
        for (var tag in result){
         var r=result[tag];
                for (var inD in input) 
                r = r.replace(`#${inD}#`, input[inD]);
                result[tag]=r;
```

How to change value if variable is nested array of objects? (example 2)

```
2. "result": [
            {
                "id": "#id#",
                "number": "#number#",
                "status": "Актуален",
            }
          ]
```

Comment: @Jamiec could you explain with example?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the results array using forEach and for each iteration call the function you created.

```
result.forEach(function(res){
   yourReplaceValuesFunction(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code already works, if I make the functional code  method `parseResult` in this example:

```js
const result = {
  "id": "#id#",
  "number": "#number#",
};
const input = {
  "id": "2",
  "number": "2585112"
};

function parseResult(result, input) {
  if (result) {
    for (var tag in result) {
      var r = result[tag];
      for (var inD in input)
        r = r.replace(`#${inD}#`, input[inD]);
      result[tag] = r;
    }
  }
}

parseResult(result, input)
console.log(result);
```

Now to make that work with an array of result, you can just enumerate the array calling the method:

```js
const result = [{
  "id": "#id#",
  "number": "#number#",
  "status": "Актуален",
}];
const input = {
  "id": "2",
  "number": "2585112"
};

function parseResult(result, input) {
  if (result) {
    for (var tag in result) {
      var r = result[tag];
      for (var inD in input)
        r = r.replace(`#${inD}#`, input[inD]);
      result[tag] = r;
    }
  }
}

for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
  parseResult(result[i], input) 
console.log(result);
```